# How to use jquery and other .js libraries with Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, angular

I don't know whether this question belongs to Angular2 or not. But I'm using Angular2 and want to integrate [this demo shown here - (please check its working demo and animated content)](http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations/) using HTML,CSS & JS. This demo shows bootstrap's carousel with animated inner content.

[This is my Demo in Plunker with Angular2](http://plnkr.co/edit/1xjgXhMicLyz8vsfJJ8Y?p=preview). I have tried to integrate it and everything works fine except I can't see animation for inner content of carousel as shown in article.

Also please guide how to use jQuery and other JS libraries with Angular2?

***index.html***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>



   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Demo scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Animate.css library -->
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>
```

**demo.js**

```
/* Demo Scripts for Bootstrap Carousel and Animate.css article
* on SitePoint by Maria Antonietta Perna
*/
(function( $ ) {

    //Function to animate slider captions 
    function doAnimations( elems ) {
        //Cache the animationend event in a variable
        var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

        elems.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $animationType = $this.data('animation');
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }

    //Variables on page load 
    var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
        $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

    //Initialize carousel 
    $myCarousel.carousel();

    //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

    //Pause carousel  
    $myCarousel.carousel('pause');


    //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
    $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
        doAnimations($animatingElems);
    });  

})(jQuery);
```

How to use this demo.js which contains jQuery code within Angular2 app?

Comment: No its not like that. I have followed what article says. Everything works fine even. But the problem is I can't see animated inner content as shown in article. So can't figure it out. is there something to be done with Angular2 or just something is missing that I can't figure out.

Comment: Without angular2 it works and it doesn't have any problem. I have anuglar2 app and want to implement. that's it. but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have read my question. I have clearly mentioned that I don't know whether it belongs to angular2 or not. but the thing is I want to use it in angular2 app. With angular2 app it doens't work. I have provided plunker or my work. you can check it. everything works. Only I want to have animated content of carousel which is not working. for that article uses `animation.css` file and `demo.js (jquery code)`. But it just doesn't work.  please help.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this was a Plunker link. The question should contain the relevant parts directly not just link to other sites.

Comment: But how can i provide part when there is no error. only animation is not working. Moreover `demo.js` contains `jquery part` So i think there should be some problem. But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your jQuery code after angular2 component initialized. I've changed your `app.component.ts` a bit:

```
import {Component,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

declare var RunAnim;
declare var jQuery;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

  constructor(){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    RunAnim(jQuery);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
  }
}

/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

Declarations of `RunAnim` and `jQuery` are for visibility in TS they are available global.

And your jQuery code I've made a named function `RunAnim`:

```
/* Demo Scripts for Bootstrap Carousel and Animate.css article
* on SitePoint by Maria Antonietta Perna
*/
(window.RunAnim=function( $ ) {

    //Function to animate slider captions 
    function doAnimations( elems ) {
        //Cache the animationend event in a variable
        var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

        elems.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $animationType = $this.data('animation');
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }

    //Variables on page load 
    var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
        $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

    //Initialize carousel 
    $myCarousel.carousel();

    //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

    //Pause carousel  
    $myCarousel.carousel('pause');


    //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
    $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
        doAnimations($animatingElems);
    });  

});
```

Comment: Much to my surprise this actually worked!  Thank you.